# PHP JSON to csv with headers

Tags: php, json, csv, curl

I am receiving JSON from a cURL post and it looks something like the following:

```
{"status":"ok","sent":177,"delivered":0,"bounced":5,"hardBounced":0,"softBounced":5,"opened":[46,81],"clicked":[5,5],"notsent":[2,2],"notopened":126,"optout":0,"spam":0,"lastOpen":"1 day ago","lastClick":"13 days ago","lastOpenTS":1459808038636,"lastClickTS":1458752521593,"rebroadcast":0,"rebroadcastClick":0,"msgId":"s-04ac-1603","subject":"Blah blah Conference and Exposition","title":"Blah followup 03.22.16","sentto":["l-160f"],"suppressedon":[]}
```

I am editing the original post to show progress with the help of those commenting:

To view what is being converted from a json like string to an array/object:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch_list);
$jsonObj = print_r(json_decode($result, true));
var_dump($jsonObj);die();
```

Which yields the following:

```
Array
(
[status] => ok
[sent] => 177
[delivered] => 0
[bounced] => 5
[hardBounced] => 0
[softBounced] => 5
[opened] => Array
    (
        [0] => 46
        [1] => 81
    )

[clicked] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )

[notsent] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[notopened] => 126
[optout] => 0
[spam] => 0
[lastOpen] => 1 day ago
[lastClick] => 14 days ago
[lastOpenTS] => 1459808038636
[lastClickTS] => 1458752521593
[rebroadcast] => 0
[rebroadcastClick] => 0
[msgId] => s-04ac-1603
[subject] => AFSA Vehicle Finance Conference and Exposition
[title] => AFSA follow up 03.22.16
[sentto] => Array
    (
        [0] => l-160f
    )

[suppressedon] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

At this point, I am thinking alright, I have converted it into an array, which should lead to creating the csv file and I can use the code that everyone has recommended in so many posts and I did receive an error, but that was corrected by the if statement after the fopen.
All together it is now creating a csv file with nothing inside of it:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch_list);
$jsonObj = print_r(json_decode($result));

if(!file_exists('/tmp/' . $msgId . '_' . $yearMonComb . '.csv')) {
    $f = fopen('/tmp/' . $msgId . '_' . $yearMonComb . '.csv', 'w');
    if (is_array($jsonObj) || is_object($jsonObj)) {
        $firstLineKeys = false;
        foreach ($jsonObj as $line) {
            if (empty($firstLineKeys)) {
                $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
                fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys);
                $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
            }
            fputcsv($f, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $line));
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Please post the output from `print_r($strToArr)` so we can see exactly what you are passing into `fputcsv()` (which is expected to be a simple single-dimensional array)

Comment: The nesting of `json_encode()` within `json_decode()` is a little suspicious - what are the original contents of `$result`? Please post `var_dump($result)` as well. If it isn't something that can be encoded to json, that will return `false`, and the `json_decode()` will in turn not produce something usable by `fputcsv()`.

Comment: print_r($strToArr) produces the same as print_r(result). I guess I am not making an array at all

Comment: So you mean to say that `$strToArr` contains a JSON string? That would be the problem, because `fputcsv()` writes CSV linewise, by taking in an input array to write out as CSV columns.

Comment: I have taken out the json_encode and I can see an array - ty - let me try to run the file once more

Comment: Taking off the json_encode has created a csv file with just the values and no headers or column names. I tried making an array with just the headers, followed by fputcsv of the headers, then array from the curl post - $headers = array("status, sent, delivered, bounced, hardBounced, softBounced, opened, clicked, notsent, notopened, optout, spam, lastOpen, lastClick, LastOpenTS, lastClickTS, rebroadcast, rebroadcastClick, msgId, subject, title, sentto, suppressedon");
    fputcsv($f, array_keys($headers), ',');
    fputcsv($f, array_values($strToArr), ','); - but no success - no column names

Comment: Please edit the original post above to show what you have right now. You should be on the right track with the values to `fputcsv()`. The `$headers` array looks like you've caused a problem by using `array_keys()` on it. All you may need for the headers is `array_keys($strToArr)` but it is still not obvious to me exactly what the contents of `$strToArr` are. If it is associative with the correct order, then calling `array_keys()` and sending that to `fputcsv()` will produce your header row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of a co-worker and the comments that some of you made, here is what works for my situation:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch_list);
$jsonObj = json_decode($result, true);

$f = fopen('/tmp/' . $msgId . '_' . $yearMonComb . '.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($f, array_keys($jsonObj));
$transposed = array();

if (is_array($jsonObj)) {
    foreach($jsonObj as $key => $record){
        if(is_array($record) && count($record) > 0){
            $target = count($record) - 1;
            $transposed[$key] = $jsonObj[$key][$target];
        }else{
            $transposed[$key] = $record;
        }
    }
    fputcsv($f, array_values($transposed));
}
fclose($f);

echo $result;
curl_close($ch_list);
```

This is the json data after doing a print_r:

```
Array
(
[status] => ok
[sent] => 177
[delivered] => 0
[bounced] => 5
[hardBounced] => 0
[softBounced] => 5
[opened] => Array
    (
        [0] => 46
        [1] => 81
    )

[clicked] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )

[notsent] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[notopened] => 126
[optout] => 0
[spam] => 0
[lastOpen] => 1 day ago
[lastClick] => 14 days ago
[lastOpenTS] => 1459808038636
[lastClickTS] => 1458752521593
[rebroadcast] => 0
[rebroadcastClick] => 0
[msgId] => s-04ac-1603
[subject] => Blah blah Conference and Exposition
[title] => Blah blah follow up 03.22.16
[sentto] => Array
    (
        [0] => l-160f
    )

[suppressedon] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

The result was a 398 byte csv file.

To answer @axiac's question with the case where the array has an array as it's value. The conditional tests for an array:

```
if(is_array($record) && count($record) > 0)
```

If there is an array, then get the last element of the array.

I hope this helps someone, because this was driving me nuts

Another edit because I found a way to loop through an array of an array

I created a separate php file to gather the items that are arrays within the array - with the array being in the item $jsonObj['result'] of the parent array

```
        $jsonObj = json_decode($result, true);
        $f = fopen($value . '-sent.csv', 'w');

        $headers = array('listid', 'name', 'when', 'recid', 'email', 'ts');

        if (is_array($jsonObj)) {
            fputcsv($f, $headers);
            foreach ($jsonObj['result'] as $fields) {
                fputcsv($f, $fields);
            }
        }
        fclose($f);

        curl_close($ch_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch_list);
// Decode the JSON representation into PHP data structures
// The second argument asks to return arrays (TRUE), not objects (FALSE or missing)
$data = json_decode($result, true);

$f = fopen($filename, 'w');

// Header line: the field names (keys in $data)
fputcsv($f, array_keys($data), ',');
// Data line (can use array_values($data) or just $data as the 2nd argument)
fputcsv($f, array_values($data), ',');

fclose($f);
```

Comment: Still produces an empty file

Comment: The code I posted doesn't do any error handling. You should do it. Maybe `$result` is `FALSE` (because the HTTP request failed). I tried it with the JSON you posted (instead of calling `curl_exec()`) and it worked fine. Apart from the fact that the array decoded from the JSON contains arrays for some keys (and they cannot be represented in CSV format as they are).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that before I stumbled onto these other issues - how am I going to deal with arrays within the array. I have tried to just echo $result and deal with it using javascript, but then I can not create a csv file. It is driving me nuts